# Symfony2 firewall, ROLE_USER has access to /admin

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with the firewall thing in Symfony2.

I have these in my security.yml file

```
- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/users, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

In my menu builder im using isGranted and this works perfect, if I login with my ROLE_USER user, the menu does not build the admin menu.

But if I manually type /admin in the browser I get the admin pages. (this happens both in production and dev envoirenment)

In the toolbar in dev env I can see the user dont have the ROLE_ADMIN role

If I dont login at all, I only see the login page, so here is everything fine

Full security.yml: https://gist.github.com/lsv/2e9dce622fd82d31853c

Full config.yml: https://gist.github.com/lsv/ec87592f911262af5417

Im using FOSUserbundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entries in `access_control` [should be in the order from more specific to more general](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#understanding-how-access-control-works). So, in your case, they should be in the following order:

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```